# Where are headers stored for civimail

Tags: civimail, mosaico, header-footer

We're using Mosaico Templates for our newsletter. When the newsletter is published it comes with a legacy header that was not visible when composing the newsletter.  How do I get rid of that header?
I'm guessing the header is a remnant of a pre-Mosaico template that we used. I disabled a similar looking header in Administer>Communicatons>MessageTemplates but test versions of the Mosaico newsletter still contain the legacy header.
We're using CiviCRM 5.50.3 on Joomla! 3.10.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked under Mailings - Headers, Footer and Automated Messages? Is that the header you're seeing?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the legacy header which I was trying to delete was in Mailings - Headers, Footer and Automated Messages.  I found Mosaico templates that were created when the legacy header was active still reproduced the header even after I disabled it.  I found that in order to eliminate the header from the mail output I had to create a new template *after* disabling the header.

Comment: That's weird. I don't think it's supposed to work that way. So the header is showing up in the actual sent mail? If you look in the mailing report at View complete message, does the header show up there too?

Comment: Yes, Lars, before I found the header in Mailings>Headers, Footers and Automated messages the header was showing up in the mailing report at View Complete Message..  I thought that disabling that header would take immediate effect in all templates. Now I understand it takes effect only upon editing a template or creating a new template.